# Laurent Series of function $\frac{z^2}{\cos^2z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I want to find Laurent series of function $\frac{z^2}{\cos^2z}$ in region $\frac{5\pi}{2}<|z|<\frac{7\pi}{2}$, but I do not know what to do.

Comment: Maybe it helps: $\frac{1}{\cos^2 z}=\sec^2 z=1+\tan^2z=\frac{d}{dz}\tan z$

Comment: We have
$$c_{2 n} = \frac 1 {2 \pi i} \int_{|z| = 3 \pi}
 \frac {\sec^2 z} {z^{2 n - 1}} dz =
[z^{2 n - 2}] \sec^2 z +
 \sum_{-3 \leq k < 3} \operatorname*{Res}_{z = \pi/2 + \pi k}
  \frac {\sec^2 z} {z^{2 n - 1}}, \\
[z^{2 n - 2}] \sec^2 z =
\frac{2^{2 n} (2^{2 n} - 1) |B_{2 n}|} {2 n (2 n - 2)!} [n \geq 1],$$
where $[z^n] f(z)$ is the $n$th coefficient in the Laurent expansion on $0 < |z| < r$ and $B_n$ are the Bernoulli numbers.